# VS Code orange/yellow highlight + red text issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, codehighlighter

This is driving me mad and I have no idea how to fix it! All of a sudden, VS Code decides to highlight code like this and it has nothing to do with my theme or any extensions. Does anyone else have this issue and how do I fix it?
[image: orange highlight]

I checked if it comes from themes or extensions but it doesn't. Here is a difference in my js file from non-highlighted to highlighted
[image: after]
[image]

Comment: What happens when you start VS Code like this: `code --disable-extensions` and look at tis file ?  (when that makes a difference, please post (add it to your question)  the output of: `code --list-extensions --show-versions`.

Comment: have you touched any syntax highlighting settings or colour customization settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit!! It was one of my old extensions 'TODO Highlight' that probably had an update and decided JS code was a to-do task. Never used it before, just like a few other extensions I had so a good clean-up was needed.
Thank you for your help!